# JDO Google App Engine validate user

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, persistence, jdo

I've been following the google app engine tutorial and the part that explains JDO is done under the basis of a guestbook. So when they query the persistence (BigTable i believe) they are interested in returning all the results.

I'm trying to adapt this for showing the results for the specific user but seem to be having trouble with it.

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
if(user != null) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PerManFac.get().getPersistenceManager();
    String query = "select * from " + Team.class.getName();
    List<Team> teamList = (List<Team>) pm.newQuery(query).execute();
    if(teamList.isEmpty()) {
```

Thats part of what i have so far, i need to adapt my query String to be 'where User = user' but i get issues each time.

My Team object only holds Key, User, a String and Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without JDOQL. If a user only has one team, then you can model this with an [owned one to many relationship](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/relationships.html#Owned_One_to_Many_Relationships) which is bidirectional.

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Team {
  @Persistent(mappedBy = "team")
  private List<Employee> employees;
}

@PersistenceCapable
public class Employee {
  @PrimaryKey
  private String user;

  @Persistent
  private Team team;
}
```

To get the `Employee` you can query by email:

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
User user = userService.getCurrentUser();

PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
Employee employee = pm.getObjectById(Employee.class, user.getEmail());
Team employee.getTeam();
```

If a user can be in many teams, you need to use [an unowned relationship](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/relationships.html#Unowned_Relationships). From your description, it sounds like each Team has one User (?), so you might want an unowned many-to-many relationship.

The part that isn't really well documented is that you cannot use a `User` object as a primary key (the possible types for a primary key [are quite limited](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Keys)), so you end up often using the email as the primary key. A `User` object can be a field, but to make your data model consistent, you often either use the email everywhere to refer to the user, or you use a wrapper object like I did above.

Comment: i'm getting an error using your method of:
    Exception converting test@example.com to an internal key.
I think it could be coming from somewhere else in my code but having trouble finding the source of it

Comment: Sorry, just seen your edit that you cant use a User as a primary key

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't it be nicer to use "user.getUserId()" as primary key?http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/User.html#getUserId()

Comment: It looks like User.getUserId() would be a good choice, but I've never tried it. If you have and it worked, I'll update the answer